# Adjusting Story Points on Split of User Story in MSF Agile 5.0

Tags: tfs, agile

I've got a question regarding adjustment of the story points when you break the large story to smaller stories.

Let me be more specific.
Lets say I have large user story that I cannot fit in one sprint and I'd like to split it for 3 smaller stories. My initial estimation of original story was 90 points. When I spit the story for three equal 30 points each. Everything is nice and beautiful, but I forgot to change initial story points to 0, so all my charts are going crazy!!! Sounds familiar?!...

So my question is: Is there any mechanism to automatically adjust initial story points when I create sub-stories and assign story points to sub-story?

Answer (score 1):

There is some [add-on on codeplex](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/) I believe that could be used to accomplish this.

It is used for automatic calculation of field values.

Comment: Thanks! The plug in is really useful, however, it doesn't deal with the story points :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do this in TFS 2010 (I have confirmed that with the team lead). So you would have to make sure that the points add up :(